# create stored procedure for when user login that time display there products in ecommers website

Tags: mysql, sql

create stored procedure for when user login that time display there products in eCommerce website..
I am create a eCommerce website.In that different user having there own product.I want to create stored procedure using cursor..when user login with there email id and password that time display there own products only on dashboard.
here I am create procedure but it gives some error..so,please suggest the answer

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test1 (cur in sys_refcursor)
as
BEGIN
for r in(select id from temp_tbl)
loop
insert into temp_tbl values(select        
            usr_login.usr_id,     
            stx_main_cat.main_cat_name,
            usr_profile.main_cat_id,
            usr_profile.usr_name,
            usr_profile.usr_email,
            usr_profile.usr_address,
            usr_profile.pincode,
            usr_profile.comp_logo,
            usr_profile.comp_name,
            usr_profile.contact_one,
            usr_profile.contact_two,
            usr_profile.usr_dob,
            usr_profile.country,
            usr_profile.state,
            usr_profile.city

   from usr_profile inner join stx_main_cat
   on usr_profile.main_cat_id = stx_main_cat.main_cat_id
   inner join usr_login
   on usr_login.usr_id = usr_profile.usr_id
   where usr_login.usr_id = r.usr_id);

end loop
open cur for
select id,main_cat_name,main_cat_id,usr_nm,city from temp_tbl
end;
```

or

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE dbo.test

(usr_email varchar(150),

usr_password varchar(500),

usr_id int out)

IS

cursor c2 is
    select        
            usr_login.usr_id,     
            stx_main_cat.main_cat_name,
            usr_profile.main_cat_id,
            usr_profile.usr_name,
            usr_profile.usr_email,
            usr_profile.usr_address,
            usr_profile.pincode,
            usr_profile.comp_logo,
            usr_profile.comp_name,
            usr_profile.contact_one,
            usr_profile.contact_two,
            usr_profile.usr_dob,
            usr_profile.country,
            usr_profile.state,
            usr_profile.city

   from usr_profile inner join stx_main_cat
   on usr_profile.main_cat_id = stx_main_cat.main_cat_id
   inner join usr_login
   on usr_login.usr_id = usr_profile.usr_id;
```

Comment: Using a `cursor` it's a bad idea...can you be more specific or update your question?...I can't understand the first part....

Comment: we are making a barter site and in that if any user will login then after login in dashboard home page user will only see there own products which they are uploaded.so,for that i am creating stored procedure.so,what will be the better way to success above scenario.

Comment: You are trying to build something like a shopping cart, an e-commerce site...there is plenty of information about how to accomplish that on the internet, you don't have to reinvent the wheel....also why a `cursor`? Maybe you come from an Oracle background?

Comment: i want to store user_id in one variable.and that variable use in my java code.related that user id I want to display user details.

Comment: can you understand my question??

Comment: Yeah, I understand your question... I am also trying to give you an advice, that your abstraction is wrong... In MySQL you don't need a cursor to return a result(that's why I ask you if you have an Oracle background)....also you are not being specific with the Java technologies that you are using to build your site... Also you can store your user_id in an HttpSession

Comment: how can i do this???? please give me the code or query